# Adding download option to website

Tags: language-agnostic

I have been roped in to help design a website for a local charity.  I am currently a university student that has experience designing sites to good effect (Within university).  I am comfortable using the relevant languages and packages.  What I am not so sure about is hosting.

If I have a site that has a newsletter, for example.  If I wanted the user to be able to download that newsletter, would I simply have that file uploaded somewhere on the hosting server and simply provide a link to that file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Although you might also wish to use a [Content-Disposition HTTP header](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download) to ensure that the file gets saved rather than opened in the default application for whatever file type it uses.

Comment: Thanks.  Will have a look at that link.

Comment: That looks exactly what I am looking for.  One further question, if I build a site using this, are host providers able to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's really all you have to do. The only thing is if its a file that the users browser will attempt to open then you need to force the download like David said, this would be the case for a pdf file, such as a newsletter like you said. And yes, to answer your other question, all hosting providers will support downloads like this.